# SQL Server Query on joining two tables correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

One is a Claims table, the other contains Edits

I am joining by ClaimID

I only want ClaimIDs that have a 205 Edit, but not 913. What do I need to do for the join?

so lets say Edits is e and Im checking e.RuleID can have 205, but not 913 (Each claimid can have unlimited edits)

Comment: Care to make a sqlfiddle? Or maybe flesh out your question because it seem to be a simple `join` query.

Comment: Google sql tutorial and read 1 or 2 pages, then try writing a query and if you have a problem post it here.

Comment: @Sashenka, it's not an inner join - there are multiple Edits on a single Claim.  The OP is looking for Claims that have a 205 edit, but not a 913 edit.

Comment: The question could have been clearer, but it's reasonable. The answer is not obvious, even having read a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Claims AS c
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM Edits AS e1
    WHERE c.ClaimID = e1.ClaimID 
    AND e1.RuleId=205)
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM Edits AS e2
    WHERE c.ClaimID = e2.ClaimID
    AND e2.RuleId=913)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Edit205.ClaimID
FROM Edits Edit205
LEFT JOIN Edits Edit913
ON Edit205.ClaimID = Edit913.ClaimID AND Edit913.RuleID = 913
WHERE Edit205.RuleID = 205
AND Edit913.ClaimID IS NULL
```

Working sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c8ac/1)

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
SELECT *
FROM Claims C
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM Edits 
                 WHERE Edit = 913 AND ClaimId = C.ClaimId)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM Edits 
            WHERE Edit = 205 AND ClaimId = C.ClaimId)
```